# How to view the number of unread Outlook messages in task bar (tray)

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange

I'd like to be able to know how many unread emails I have in my Outlook 2007 inbox without having to open outlook.  Is there a way to have a tray icon with this number be displayed?  I can't use tools that aren't specifically for outlook or exchange as IMAP is not enabled on our exchange server.

Comment: For Windows 7? Have you looked at the many desktop Gadgets available for interfacing with Outlook?

Comment: I'm on vista.  Desktop gadgets aren't that useful to me.  Minimizing all my open windows and restoring them afterwards is more work than just opening the outlook window.